# Fluent docker tail vs docker fluentd logging driver

Tags: logging, docker, fluentd

I can't decide which is more robust in real-life applications:

A) using fluentd docker logging driver - docker sends its data to fluentd driver

B) using fleund to tail default docker json logs.

Why I have a problem with A? Well, it is like "inversion of control" principle in programming:

- it is one more dependency, docker will not start if it is not set correctly
- Filtering and formatting different types of logs may be a pain, when all logs are forwarded as stdout to the same port.
- The biggest issue: in case of fluentd failure, there is no option to recover the logs!

I am leaning more to solution B, but I miss some experience on this subject. Do I miss something?

Comment: If "Filtering and formatting different types of logs is a serious pain" then why fluentd at all? If you don't have a system to search/sort on the aggregation side what is fluentd for?

Comment: @Matt yeah, i made slight change in the question. However, the second thing concern me more!